# Visual Basic 2d array from .dat file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I'm trying to pull some data from two text files. The first loads and populates the listboxes perfectly. The second text file is where I'm having trouble. I can't seem to get it to load correctly. I'm trying to put it into a 2D array, MileageAr. The messagebox is to troubleshoot if it is loading into the array correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Sample Data from SDMileage.dat

```
1,54,465,58,488,484
5,54,654,87,841,844
```

etc....

```
Public Class ArrayFun
Dim MileageAr(10, 10) As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim State As New System.IO.StreamReader("SDCities.dat")
    Dim strState As String
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Do While State.Peek <> -1
        strState = State.ReadLine
        lstFrom.Items.Add(strState)
        lstTo.Items.Add(strState)
    Loop


    Dim Mileage As New System.IO.StreamReader("SDMileage.dat")
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim strSplit() As String

    Do While State.Peek <> -1
        strLine = Mileage.ReadLine
        strSplit = strLine.Split(",")
        j = 0
        For Each miles In strSplit
            MileageAr(i, j) = miles
            j += 1
        Next
        i += 1
    Loop
    State.Close()
    Mileage.Close()

End Sub


Private Sub lstTo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstTo.SelectedIndexChanged
    MsgBox(MileageAr(1, 1))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Does it throws an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Mileage As New System.IO.StreamReader("SDMileage.dat")
Dim strLine As String
Dim strSplit() As String
```

**CHANGE THIS TO Mileage.Peek**

```
Do While State.Peek <> -1
    strLine = Mileage.ReadLine
    strSplit = strLine.Split(",")
```

Try looping this way instead

```
Dim Mileage As System.IO.TextReader = New StreamReader("SDMileaage.dat")

do while ((strline = Mileage.ReadLine) <> nothing)
```

The Peek method might be fine, I just typically use the code above when working with text files, might be worth a shot...

Comment: No error, I just can't seem to get any output from the array, which means it isn't populating correctly

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the line before the assignment into the array and check the value, then single step through and see if the array gets populated?  The code appears OK, so I am not if the problem might not be when you try to use the array.

Comment: So going through step by step it reads the first line of the text file fine, I can output that, but there is more then one line in this file.

Comment: Thank you Sparky for your help. What I was doing wrong was I didn't size the array large enough, and that was why. Is there a way to autosize the array?